# ¿Como Configuración de Sequelize en node.js?

Tags: nodejs, npm, orm

esto mas que una pregunta es un aporte de como solucione un "`problema`" que tuve `recientemente` con la dependencia de `node.js` `Sequelize` (**`v5.19.7`**).

si vamos a la documentación de Sequelize (`https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getting-started.html`), nos indica que con la siguiente fracción de código:

```
const Sequelize =require('sequelize');

const sequelize =new Sequelize('tienda','postgres','password',{
    host:'localhost',
    dialect:'postgres',
    "logging": false,
    pool:{
        max:5,
        min:0,
        require:30000,
        idle:10000 
    }
});
sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
   //
    module.exports=sequelize;
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });

module.exports=sequelize;
```

ya podemos empezar a modelar y ejecutar una consulta de la siguiente manera:

aquí el modelado de la tabla producto:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize= require('../database/database'); 

const Producto= sequelize.define('producto',{
    id:{
        type:Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey:true
    },
    nombre:{
        type:Sequelize.TEXT
    },
    descripcion:{
        type:Sequelize.TEXT
    },
    monto:{
        type:Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    fecha:{
        type:Sequelize.DATE
    },
    estado:{
        type:Sequelize.BOOLEAN
    }
});
module.exports=Producto;
```

aquí la consulta:

```
const producto = require("../models/producto");
proyectoCtrl.createProyecto = async (req, res) => {
  var producto = req.body; 
  producto.estado=true;
  producto = await Producto.create(producto, {
    fields: ["nombre", "descripcion", "monto", "fecha", "estado"]
  })
    .then(proyecto => {
      res.json(proyecto);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).json({
        error:
          "el json solo posee 'nombre','descripcion','monto','fecha','estado'" 
      });
    });
};
```

pero esto por defecto genera lo siguiente:

```
SELECT "id", "nombre", "descripcion", "monto", "fecha", "estado" 
FROM "proyectos" AS "proyecto" WHERE "proyecto"."estado" = true;
```

en ves de :

```
SELECT "id", "nombre", "descripcion", "monto", "fecha", "estado" 
FROM "proyecto" AS "proyecto" WHERE "proyecto"."estado" = true;
```

lo cual genera un `error` si nuestra tabla se llama `proyecto` en ves de `proyectos`

para solucionar esto debemos agregar la configurar en `zequelize` de la siguiente manera:

```
const Sequelize =require('sequelize');

const sequelize =new Sequelize('tienda','postgres','password',{
    host:'localhost',
    dialect:'postgres',
    "logging": false,
    define: { 
        freezeTableName: true, 
        timestamps: false
    },
    pool:{
        max:5,
        min:0,
        require:30000,
        idle:10000 
    }
});
sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
   //
    module.exports=sequelize;
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });

module.exports=sequelize;
```

la configuracion que soluciona en si este "problema" es `freezeTableName: true`.

```
 define: {   
      freezeTableName: true
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequelize como ORM trata de ser inteligente. En este sentido ofrece valores por defecto para una serie de características de los modelos:

- el nombre de la tabla se infiere del nombre del modelo llevándolo al plural si no se indica explícitamente
- el campo primary key de la tabla se infiere como de nombre id, tipo numérico y auto incremental si no se indica explícitamente
- se incluyen campos para registrar la fecha de creación y fecha de ultima modificación de cada record a no ser que explícitamente se indique lo contrario
- en modo paranoico se registra la fecha de eliminación de cada record en un campo adicional y nunca se eliminan los records de la base de datos.

Esto es una via por la cual Sequelize trata de hacernos la vida mas fácil. Pero puede ser que en algunos casos esto interfiera con nuestro trabajo (por ejemplo cuando se trabaja con tablas existentes que no siguen estas convenciones). Los desarrolladores de Sequelize reconocen este hecho y permiten configurar todos estos comportamientos.

En el caso del nombre de la tabla. Tal como se indica en la documentación de [definición de modelo](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/models-definition.html) sección de configuracion. Es posible hacerlo usando el parámetro `tableName`. Usar este parámetro permite modificar el nombre de la tabla para cada modelo.

En el caso del modelo `producto`, por defecto el nombre de la tabla seria `productos`. Si se desea usar el nombre de tabla `producto` el modelo se puede definir de la siguiente forma:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize= require('../database/database'); 

const Producto= sequelize.define('producto',{
    id:{
        type:Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey:true
    },
    nombre:{
        type:Sequelize.TEXT
    },
    descripcion:{
        type:Sequelize.TEXT
    },
    monto:{
        type:Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    fecha:{
        type:Sequelize.DATE
    },
    estado:{
        type:Sequelize.BOOLEAN
    }
}, {
    tableName: 'producto'
});
module.exports=Producto;
```

`freezeTableName` tal como se muestra arriba puede usarse en este caso. Pues lo que hace es usar el nombre del modelo como nombre de la tabla. Ahora bien este parámetro puede usarse tanto al definir los parámetros de la conexión como al definir el modelo. Como mismo se muestra en el caso de `tableName`. No obstante no ofrece el mismo grado de flexibilidad que `tableName`. Piense por ejemplo en el caso de dos modelos que son vistas de una misma tabla.

Comment: el `tableName` tiene la desventaja de que es requerido en cada modelo, pero si también es una manera de personalizar mas exclusivamente la tabla que se desea gracias por el aporte